# How do I make my ImageView a fixed size regardless of the size of the bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

So I'm loading images from a web service, but the size of the images are sometimes smaller or bigger than other images and the visualization looks silly when I put them in a ListView in android.  I'd like to fix the size of my ImageView so that it only shows a portion of the image if it's larger than a preset amount.  I've tried everything I can think of setting the setMaxWidth/setMaxHeight, setting the scale type to centerCrop, using ClipableDrawable wrapping my BitmapDrawable, setting using Drawable.setBounds().  I've tried setting in the XML and programmatically, but neither worked.  I'm very surprised setting max width/height didn't do anything.  Below is the XML I'm using ImageView definition in my layout file:

```
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/recipeImage"
           android:maxHeight="64px"
           android:maxWidth="64px"
           android:scaleType="centerCrop"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_marginRight="6dip"/>
```

But,nothing has worked.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just delete the `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` attributes and enter your units in `layout_width` and `layout_height` appropriately. But do not use the `px` unit - use `dp` instead, because these are device-independent.

Comment: How about `minHeight` and `minWidth`?

Answer (score 4):

This will fit the image in the specified height and width, irrespective of image size.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image5"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Get ImageVIews as facebook posts.    
Glide.with(context).load(link)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.aboutlogo)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imageView);`

        <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="center"/>
```